How to clear an input field on click?
I need to clear total number of devices input field once clicked on checkbox:
If I click on the checkbox Android a number of devices input field pops up then I select the amount of devices and total number of devices input automatically fills in the number, I would like to clear that number when unchecking the Android checkbox: sample of form here:
https://mobile-guardian.webflow.io/form-template
This is the what the script is at the moment:
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const deviceInputs = document.querySelectorAll('#chromebook-device, #windows-device, #macos-device, #android-device, #ios-device');
    const totalInput = document.getElementById('total-device');

    deviceInputs.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener('input', function() {
            let totalDevices = 0;
            deviceInputs.forEach(input => {
                const number = parseInt(input.value, 10) || 0;
                totalDevices += number;
            });
            totalInput.value = totalDevices;
        });
    });
});
</script>


Please add an example of the markup used by this script.

You would have added a code to handle checkbox click/change events as well, right? can you please put that code as well here?

I create array of objects to set dependances idChBox and idTextInput, modify getters of nodeList and create function to get actual nodeList of textInputs. If desired, the code can be shortened.
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // array of objects which will contain id's of chBoxes and textInputs
  const devicesList = [
    { textInputId:"chromebook-device", chboxInputId:"Chromebook" },
    { textInputId:"windows-device", chboxInputId:"Windows" },
    { textInputId:"macos-device", chboxInputId:"macOS" },
    { textInputId:"android-device", chboxInputId:"Android" },
    { textInputId:"ios-device", chboxInputId:"iOS" },
  ];

  const initialValue = "";
  // old syntax
  // const deviceInputs =  document.querySelectorAll('#chromebook-device, #windows-device, #macos-device, #android-device, #ios-device ');
  const tmpStr1 = devicesList.reduce( (accumulator,curV,curInd)=>{ const comma=curInd===0?"":","; accumulator+=`${comma} #${curV.textInputId}`; return accumulator},initialValue );
  const deviceInputs =  document.querySelectorAll( tmpStr1 );

  // function which will get textField id by checkbox id
  const getTextInputIdByChbxId = ( chbxId )=>{
    const filteredArr = devicesList.filter( element=> element.chboxInputId===chbxId );
    const textFieldId = filteredArr[0].textInputId;
    return textFieldId;
  }
  
  // function which will get textField object by checkbox id
  const getTextInputByChbxId = ( chbxId )=>{
    const textInputId = getTextInputIdByChbxId(chbxId);
    const targetTextField = document.getElementById( textInputId );
    return targetTextField;
  }
  
  // function which will clear textField object by checkbox id
  const clearTextInputByChbxId = ( chbxId )=>{
    const textInput = getTextInputByChbxId(chbxId);
    textInput.value = "";
  }
  
  // function which will get actual checked textinputs
  const getDeviceInputs = ( devicesList )=>{
    const initialValue = "";
    // old syntax
    // const deviceInputs2 = document.querySelectorAll('#Chromebook:checked,#Windows:checked,#macOS:checked,#Android:checked,#iOS:checked');
    const tmpStr2 = devicesList.reduce( (accumulator,curV,curInd)=>{ const comma=curInd===0?"":","; accumulator+=`${comma} #${curV.chboxInputId}:checked`; return accumulator},initialValue );
    const deviceInputs2 = document.querySelectorAll( tmpStr2 );
    const newTmpArrForTextInputs = [];
    deviceInputs2.forEach(element => {
      const textInputId = getTextInputIdByChbxId(element.id);
      newTmpArrForTextInputs.push(`#${ textInputId }`)
    });
    const newTmpStrForTextInputs = newTmpArrForTextInputs.join(", ");
    const newDeviceInputs =  document.querySelectorAll( newTmpStrForTextInputs );
    return newDeviceInputs;
  }

  const totalInput = document.getElementById('total-device');

  deviceInputs.forEach(input => {
      input.addEventListener('input', function(ev) {
          clearTextInputByChbxId(ev.target.id);
          let totalDevices = 0;
          getDeviceInputs(devicesList).forEach(input => {
              const number = parseInt(input.value, 10) || 0;
              totalDevices += number;
          });
          totalInput.value = totalDevices;
      });
  });
});

To make the code shorter, I recommend giving classes for checkboxes and text fields (general, typed and clarifying).
Example chbox: os-class os-text android (mac , ios)
Example text:  os-class os-chbx android (mac , ios)
Then you don't need to create devicesList and use classes instead.

Thanks for this, I have pasted the whole script in, but the function is doing the exact same thing, not clearing

@RyanSmith can you save this code as js file and connect it via script tag?

@RyanSmith I update code, now also clear text fields by clearTextInputByChbxId() function

You can set the value of the input element to an empty string when you check or uncheck one of the check boxes.
Beside that I think that <fieldset> could be useful in your case. When a field set is disabled the form fields inside the field set are not included in the submitted data. At the same time the disabled property can be used for hiding the input element. The elements property on a field set refers to all the input elements in that field set -- also handy.


document.forms.form01.devicetypes.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  // enable/disable fieldset
  form[`fieldset_${e.target.value}`].disabled = !e.target.checked;
  // set the value to 0
  form[e.target.value].value = '';
  update_total(form);
});

document.forms.form01.fieldset_devices.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  update_total(form);
});

function update_total(form) {
  let total = [...form['fieldset_devices'].elements]
                .filter(elm => elm.valueAsNumber)
                .reduce((total, elm) => total + elm.valueAsNumber, 0);
  form.total.value = total;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

fieldset:disabled {
  display: none;
}
<form name="form01">
  <fieldset name="devicetypes">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="androiddevices"> Android</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="iosdevices"> iOS</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="fieldset_devices">
    <fieldset name="fieldset_androiddevices" disabled>
      <label>Number of Android devices<input type="number" name="androiddevices"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="fieldset_iosdevices" disabled>
      <label>Number of iOS devices<input type="number" name="iosdevices"></label>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <label>Total number of devices: <input name="total"></label>
</form>




I think this will be solve your problem.
Declare your process as function
function calculateTotal(inputs){
   let totalDevices = 0;
   inputs.forEach(input => {
   const number = parseInt(input.value, 10) || 0;
   totalDevices += number;
   });
   totalInput.value = totalDevices;
   return totalDevices;
}

add event listener for checkbox
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".your-checkbox-class");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
     checkbox.addEventListener('change',()=>{
         calculateTotal(deviceInputs);
      })
   })
})

If you want to empty totalInput as you said just try
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".your-checkbox-class");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
     checkbox.addEventListener('change',()=>{
         totalInput.value = "";
      })
   })
})


Thinking that this answer is not valid, I wonder why the friend who gave a minus score without reading it in the 3rd second gave a minus score.

I haven't downvoted you, but this doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking how they can clear the value of inputs when a specific checkbox is checked/unchecked. Your code is instead refactoring what they already have.

I just take look project link and think about solutions and this is better

I changed the answer. Add the solution as he want.

Hey guys I've tried the method but is still doing the same thing and not clearing the total input?

Is there any error or anything. Can you share html code as well and changed script

If you go document.getElemementById('your boxes class here').innerhtml('') then I think it should clear it

Putting a class in getElementById() isn't going to work, and you need to update the value of the input, not its HTML
